# Retirar ?resize= da url da imagem

Tags: wordpress, url, plugin-wordpress

Após alguns testes com o gtmetrix percebi que as imagens demoram para carregar quando são redimensionadas a partir da url, com o método "*?resize=(dimensões)*" no final da mesma.

Exemplo:
meudomininio.com/imagem.jpg (20ms)

meudomininio.com/imagem.jpg?resize=100,400 (500ms)

A minha pergunta é como desativar essa configuração, visto que o desempenho do site cai.

Uso o wordpress. Plugins EWWW e Fastern Cache ativados, .htacess configurado

Answer (score 2):

A regra geral é remover todos os plugins suspeitos (como os que você citou) e ver se o problema persiste. Caso resolva, adicione um por um novamente até achar o "culpado".

Uma vez achando o plugin que está causando a lentidão, busque infos dele e tente achar a configuração para não gerar thumbs dinamicamente. Muitos usam a biblioteca "timthumb".

Caso não dê certo, tente achar por algum redirecionamento configurado em seu .htaccess, será algo parecido com isso:

```
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9.]+)?$ /tt.php?src=/images/$2&amp;w=$1
```

**Resolvido**

O plugin "Jetpack" estava sendo utilizado. Ele é o responsável por colocar esse "?resize=(dimensões)" na url quando o otimizar imagem está ativado. Desativando essa função resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizo o Wordpress. Descobri que o plugin "Jetpack" é o responsável por colocar esse "?resize=(dimensões)" na url quando o otimizar imagem está ativado.

Então desativei essa função do plugin e tudo foi resolvido.